# Seg fault in copy constructor

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor

I'm working on an assignment in which we are manipulating *.ppm images using a "Image" class. It compiles and then seg faults when the copy constructor is called. Here it is:

```
Image::Image(const Image & imageToCopy) {
fileType = imageToCopy.fileType;
width = imageToCopy.width;
height = imageToCopy.height;
maxColor = imageToCopy.maxColor;

image = new int *[height];

for(int i=0; i < height; i++) {
    image[i] = new int [width];
    for(int j=0; j < width; j++) {
    image[i][j] = imageToCopy.image[i][j];
    }
}
}
```

Called like so:

```
Image image2(image1);
```

I'm at somewhat of a loss for why this happens. I don't know what is wrong because the code is almost identical to my constructor, which works fine. the only difference is that I have

```
image[i][j] = imageToCopy.image[i][j];
```

instead of

```
imageInputStream >> image[i][j];
```

Thoughts? Thanks

EDIT: Constructor is below:

```
Image::Image(const char* filename) {
    ifstream imageInputStream;
    imageInputStream.open(filename);

    imageInputStream >> fileType;
    imageInputStream >> width;
    imageInputStream >> height;
    imageInputStream >> maxColor;

    image = new int *[height];

    for(int i=0; i < height; i++) {
        image[i] = new int [width];
        for(int j=0; j < width; j++) {
            imageInputStream >> image[i][j];
        }
    }

    imageInputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: What are the width and height of the image you're copying?  If the sizes are sane and you're not getting a `std::bad_alloc`, at first glance it looks OK.  I'd suggest moving to `std::vector` instead of your C-style arrays though...  I'd suggest that _quite strongly_.  In fact, if you were storing the contents as `std::vector`, you probably wouldn't even _need_ a copy constructor...

Comment: Can you give us a minimal complete example? Odds are your `image1` is not well-formed.

Comment: Can you use a debugger to locate the point of failure more precisely?

Comment: Should "image = new int *[height];" be 2 dimensional? I.E have width in it too?

Comment: @Caribou: It already is two-dimensional—it's an array of pointers to int, which is the same thing as an array of arrays of int. It might be clearer to write it the other way, but it's not going to cause any problems.

Comment: Width and height are 265x314. And this is an assignment for a class and while I've dabbled with vectors some on my own we haven't gotten that far. The most troubling thing to me is that essentially the same code works when it is sitting in the main function.

Comment: @abarnert missed that sorry guys

Comment: Caribou indirectly brings up a good point: why does the width need to be jagged (different for each row), given that each row of an image presumably has the same number of pixels as every other row…

Comment: As Grigory suggested, a debugger would really help here. Is it segfaulting at the expected line (`image[i][j] = imageToCopy.image[i][j];`)? If so, is the segfault while accessing `imageToCopy.image[i]`, or `imageToCopy.image[i][j]`, `image[i]`, or `image[i][j]`? If you knew that, it would be much easier to figure out the problem.

Comment: I suppose it doesn't need to be jagged. This is actually code copied from an earlier assignment, so I didn't bother to change anything. We are essentially taking a program which had various manipulation methods in the main function and putting them into a class.

Comment: Could you add declaration of `image` to the question...

Comment: One more quick question: Do you have an destructor and assignment operator? If the answers are yes and no, are you doing something like `Image img2; img2 = img1;` anywhere?

Comment: I have a destructor, and I do not have an assignment operator. I don't do img1 = img2 anywhere. GDB gives this:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080493d7 in Image::Image(Image const&) ()

Comment: The gdb purpose was to inspect the source of the copy to determine sanity or potentially crooked data therein.

Comment: Can you give us the complete source code for Image, and for the calling code (ideally stripped down to a minimal example that still reproduces the problem, as with the sample in my answer below)? If it's too much to paste here, stick it at pastebin or your favorite alternative and give us a link.

Comment: Image.cpp: [link](http://pastebin.com/JKaiLLFM)
Image.h: [link](http://pastebin.com/QVcTdmgy)
imageLab.cpp: [link](http://pastebin.com/XdLPfCnB)

Copy constructor is called on line 35 of lmageLab.cpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the complete code, this is just a guess, but if you've created a copy constructor and a destructor but no copy assignment operator, you may get a segfault exactly like this if you try to use assignment.

And you may not think you're doing an assignment anywhere, but unless you know all the rules of C++ (which even experts don't, much less new students), it's hard to be sure. The easiest way to find out is to declare a private assignment operator and don't define it (or, if you're using C++11, declare it deleted) and see if you get a compile error.

For example:

```
struct Image {
  int width_, height_;
  int **image_;
  Image(int width, int height) : width_(width), height_(height),
                                 image_(0) {
    image_ = new int *[height_];
    for (int i = 0; i != height_; ++i) {
      image_[i] = new int[width_];
      for (int j = 0; j != width_; ++j) {
        image_[i][j] = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  Image(const Image& rhs) : width_(rhs.width_), height_(rhs.height_),
                            image_(0) {
    image_ = new int*[height_];
    for (int i = 0; i != height_; ++i) {
      image_[i] = new int[width_];
      for (int j = 0; j != width_; ++j) {
        image_[i][j] = rhs.image_[i][j];
      }
    }
  }

  /* uncomment to uncrash
  Image& operator=(const Image& rhs) {
    if (this == &rhs) return *this;
    for (int i = 0; i != height_; ++i) {
      delete [] image_[i];
    }
    delete [] image_;
    image_ = new int*[height_];
    for (int i = 0; i != height_; ++i) {
      image_[i] = new int[width_];
      for (int j = 0; j != width_; ++j) {
        image_[i][j] = rhs.image_[i][j];
      }
    }
    return *this;
  }
  */

  ~Image() {
    for (int i = 0; i != height_; ++i) {
      delete [] image_[i];
    }
    delete [] image_;
  }
};

int main(int, char*[]) {
  Image img(200, 300);
  Image img2(img);
  Image img3(100, 200);
  img3 = img2;
  return 0;
}
```

As the comment implies, if you uncomment the copy assignment operator, the whole thing works.

If this is your problem, read up on the Rule of Three ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29), [Ward's Wiki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RuleOfTheBigThree)).

Comment: Do I need to define an assignment operator if I'm not going to use it. I know that if I use it as you do in your main I need it, but I don't use assignment on any objects.

Comment: Whenever you declare a destructor, you should declare an assignment operator. Otherwise, the compiler will generate one for you, and it will be wrong. If you're sure you're never going to need it, declare it deleted (C++11) or declare it private and don't define it (C++03), but still declare it. (That way, if you're wrong, you get a compiler error instead of a mysterious runtime crash.)

Comment: Well, lo and behold, making an assignment operator method fixed it. I guess that makes a lot of the copy constructor code obsolete as well since I can just make a new object and say image2=image1. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you probably do want to define one in terms of the other. But the best way to do this is the other way around: Define a `swap` method, then define the assignment operator in terms of copy-and-swap. Then you don't need to write any of the code to check for self-assignment, delete the old values, etc. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-and-swap for details.

Answer (score 0):

I took the code you pasted at pastebin and added some logging to the two constructors.

In `Image(const char *)`, right after `imageInputStream >> maxColor`;:

```
    cout << "Image(" << filename << "): "
         << fileType << ", "
         << width << ", "
         << height << ", "
         << maxColor << endl;
```

In `Image(const Image&)`, right after `maxColor = imageToCopy.maxColor;`:

```
    cout << "Image(Image): "
         << fileType << ", "
         << width << ", "
         << height << ", "
         << maxColor << endl;
```

And here's the output:

```
Testing standard constructor, opening tux.ppm
Image(tux.ppm): P3, 0, 0, 0
Calling flip method
Calling dither method
Saving the flipped and dithered image
Creating a 2nd image object, using tux.ppm again with the standard constructor
Image(tux.ppm): P3, 32767, 1656563112, 17
```

In other words, you're reading garbage. The first time through, I happen to read 0x0 and return an empty image. Then I read 32767x1656563112 and create a huge garbage image, which takes so long that I don't want to wait around, but I could imagine that copying it would segfault.

And to verify that this is the case, look at what gets output as tux_transformed.ppm:

```
P3
0 0
0
```

Of course I don't have your tux.ppm file, but I threw a bunch of sample PPMs at it from different sources, and they all had the same problem.

As a wild guess, your problem is that you're not handling PPM comments, so you're trying to read one as, e.g., a width. But it really doesn't matter. If your code can create garbage objects, it can crash trying to copy them.